# Google cloud functions trigger to load data into big query table from storage

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create event based trigger using google cloud function which will load data from storage to biquery, however I am getting url not found error those its there into code and the bucket with file is available.

Error:

```
"Exception on /_ah/push-handlers/pubsub/projects/p974da23cefdb5965p-tp/topics/cloud-functions-sooycdpxmw6yk6x52gjf7iczou [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 171, in view_func
    function(data, context)
  File "/workspace/main.py", line 28, in csv_loader
    load_job.result()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/base.py", line 728, in result
    return super(_AsyncJob, self).result(timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py", line 261, in result
    raise self._exception
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not found: URI gs://bucket/file"
timestamp: "2023-03-22T10:01:24.518251Z"
```

**Code:**

```
import os
from google.cloud import bigquery
def csv_loader(event, context):
        print("event_key {}".format(event))
        project_id = os.environ['PROJECT']
        bq_dataset = os.environ['DATASET']
        bq_table = os.environ['TABLE']
        bucket_name = os.environ["BUCKET"]
        file_name = os.environ['FILE']
        client = bigquery.Client()
        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
                schema = [bigquery.SchemaField('OUL_GRP_ID', 'INTEGER', 'REQUIRED'),
                          bigquery.SchemaField('MERCH_LVL', 'STRING', 'REQUIRED'),
                          bigquery.SchemaField('MERCH_NBR', 'INTEGER', 'REQUIRED'),
                          bigquery.SchemaField('EXCLUDE', 'STRING', 'REQUIRED')],
                skip_leading_rows=1, source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
        )
       
        gcs_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, file_name)
        table_id = "{}.{}.{}".format(project_id, bq_dataset, bq_table)
        load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
                gcs_uri,
                table_id,
                job_config=job_config)
        
        print('Starting job {}'.format(load_job.job_id))
        print('File: {}'.format(file_name))
        load_job.result()
        print('Job finished.')
        destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)
        print('Loaded {} rows.'.format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

I am not sure where the URL is missing as its there with the code.

P.S.: Proper roles already assigned to the associated service account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been missing storage object in the code with file extension causing the issues, Now I have updated the code and it is working fine.

```
import os
import io
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage

project_id = os.environ['PROJECT']
bq_dataset = os.environ['DATASET']
bq_table = os.environ['TABLE']
bucket_name = os.environ["BUCKET"]
file_name = os.environ['FILE']
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(bq_dataset)

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)



def csv_loader(event, context):
        """Triggered by a change to a Cloud Storage bucket.
    Args:
        event (dict): The event payload.
        context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
        print("event_key {}".format(event))
        blob = bucket.blob(file_name + ".csv")
        file_content = blob.download_as_string().decode('utf-8')
        print("file_content: ", file_content)

        table_ref = dataset_ref.table(bq_table)
        
        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
                schema = [bigquery.SchemaField('OUL_GRP_ID', 'INTEGER', 'REQUIRED'),
                          bigquery.SchemaField('MERCH_LVL', 'STRING', 'REQUIRED'),
                          bigquery.SchemaField('MERCH_NBR', 'INTEGER', 'REQUIRED'),
                          bigquery.SchemaField('EXCLUDE', 'STRING', 'REQUIRED')],
                skip_leading_rows=1, source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
                write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
        )
        
        file_obj = io.StringIO(file_content)

        load_job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_file(
                file_obj,
                table_ref,
                job_config=job_config)
        
        print('Starting job {}'.format(load_job.job_id))
        print('File: {}'.format(file_name))
        load_job.result()
        print('Job finished.')
        destination_table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)
        print('Loaded {} rows.'.format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that there is an issue with the `URI` you are passing to `client.load_table_from_uri()`. You mentioned that the bucket and file exist, but maybe double-check the URI format?
You may also want to make sure that the Google Cloud Function service account you are using has the appropriate permissions to access the Cloud Storage bucket and the file
Not sure, but if all of the above are in place you can try adding a print statement to your code to debug the `gcs_uri` variable and check whether it matches the expected URI format.

```
gcs_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, file_name)
print("gcs_uri: ", gcs_uri)
>>> the correct URI format
```

Also try specifying the full path of the file in the `file_name` variable, including the path to the directory where the file is located (e.g., if the file is located in the data directory inside the bucket, you could set `file_name` to `"data/your_file_name.csv"`.